# Reload XML data without reload page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I get xml data from Mysql.. And change anything save again to mysql. 
Now i want to see changed data without reload page. How can i do it ?

I get data like that:

```
        downloadUrl("gxml.php", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);

        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

i`v tried to do it calling function like that. but didnt work..

```
        function reloaddata()
        {
         downloadUrl("gxml.php", function(doc));
        }
```

Thanks..

Comment: `downloadUrl("gxml.php", function(doc))` is syntactically wrong, what do you want to do once the xml is downloaded

Comment: whats here is wrong? its working the first time. i`m need reload it when i want..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using ajax. Pass some values from php to ajax via javascript. And then in ajax retrieve xml data do what ever you want with it. and give a response. Then use

```
success: function(){
   //append it to your html.
}
```

Comment: i have do it. But data not reloading. showing only first loading( when page opened) data.(

Answer (score 0):

your code is OK, the problem is about when it is invoked. You will need to pull the data as a response of a timer event, or some other event more related to your logic.

```
setInterval("downloadMarkers()", 10000);    // 10 seconds per call.

function downloadMarkers() {
  downloadUrl("gxml.php", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  });
}
```

Comment: i found its way. i have existing marker array. the first i must clear this array.. but how?:)